# Django DRF with NameSpace api versioning. Fix to NoReverseMatch or ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, namespaces, versioning

I want to version my api, but cannot make reverse function work.

I am following the namespace versioning schema proposed in the DRF website : [namespaceversioning](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#namespaceversioning)

I have one app called *authentication* and inside authentication folder I have :

```
 authentication/
 |
  -- models.py, apps.py, admin.py
  -- api_v1/
     |
     -- views.py
     -- serializers.py
     -- urls.py
```

In my main urls.py, I've defined

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/',include

('my_project.apps.authentication.api_v1.urls',namespace='v1'),
        ('my_project.apps.posts.api_v1.urls',namespace='v1')
     ),
    url(r'^$', lambda _: redirect('http://localhost:8888/')),
]
```

This is authentication/api_v1/urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter                       

from authentication.api_v1.views import UserViewSet                    

app_name = 'authentication'                                            
router = DefaultRouter()                                               
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, base_name='authentication-user')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And when I execute

```
./manage.py show_urls

 /api/v1/users/ authentication.api_v1.views.UserViewSet v1:authentication-user-list
 /api/v1/users/<pk>/    authentication.api_v1.views.UserViewSet v1:authentication-user-detail
```

When I am trying to reverse for example from shell, I have the following error:

```
> reverse('v1:authentication-user-detail', kwargs={'pk': '5'})

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'authentication-user-detail' not found. 'authentication-user-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

> reverse('authentication:v1:posts-job-detail', kwargs={'pk': '5'})

NoReverseMatch: 'v1' is not a registered namespace inside 'authentication'

> reverse('v1:authentication:posts-job-detail', kwargs={'pk': '5'})

NoReverseMatch: 'authentication' is not a registered namespace inside 'v1'
```

BUT, if I do not put namespace='v1' in the app urls, like this:

```
url(r'^api/v1/',include('my_project.apps.authentication.api_v1.urls')
```

Then the reverse functions works

```
> reverse('authentication:authentication-user-detail', kwargs={'pk':5})
> '/api/v1/users/5/'
```

I think I am calling the reverse in the wrong way, or maybe some configuration? 
Because if I call the api for example via postman, the endpoint is working ok.

**UPDATE:**

I think the problem is I have same namespace for two entries in my main urls.py
I will late check it. I think the solution is have only one entry in my main urls, and move all the rest to another file.

**UPDATE 2**

I think (i am not sure if its correct) I make it work like this.
In my main urls.py

```
api_v1 =[                                                              
    url(r'^api/v1/', 
        include('my_project.apps.agreements.api_v1.urls')),  
    url(r'^api/v1/',
    include('my_project.apps.authentication.api_v1.urls'))   ]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include((api_v1,'v1'), namespace="v1")),
]
```

If instead, in the url patterns I include like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(api_v1, namespace="v1")),
]
```

I have the following error:
'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

The thing is that 'v1' as the second argument, the "app_name", in fact its not an app name, I just put it there to not have the error....

Also now, the reverse I have to make it like this (it works):

```
reverse('v1:authentication:authentication-user-detail', kwargs={'pk': '5'})
'/api/v1/users/5/'
```

And not like I wanted that is:

```
reverse('v1:authentication-user-detail' . .
```

**UPDATE 3**

For the last problem, I solved it commenting app_name inside the url file from the specific app. So it would be

```
# app_name = 'authentication'                                            
router = DefaultRouter()                                               
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, base_name='authentication-user')
```

Comment: Are you importing `reverse()` from `rest_framework.reverse` or `django.urls`?

Comment: Please post your all urls file, where & how is authentication mounted ?

Comment: not sure, but isn't this a nested namespace? i.e. `reverse(authentication:v1:authentication-user-detail)`?

Comment: @A.J.Parr, yes, if not the error would be something like "reverse is not defined".

Comment: @MohammadUmair , updated the main urls

Comment: @dirkgroten , updated what is the error when try with nested namespace